# chapterstyle is prohibiting page number on right/left side

Tags: header-footer, memoir, page-numbering

What I have now is page numbers on even or odd sides, except on the first page of a chapter. I also wish for the number in the footer at the first page of a chapter to be shown on either the right or left side, depending on, if it's on an even or odd page. I have tried other methods, but non have worked (yet).
Here is the essential setup. An explanation will follow:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\setheadfoot{2\onelineskip}{\footskip}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

%%%%%%
% CHAPTER STYLES
%%%%%%
\makechapterstyle{simple}{
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{1cm}       %
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\flushleft\chaptitlefont##1}
  }

\makechapterstyle{box}{%
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{-58pt}       %
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{10mm}      %
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}   %
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{     %
    \flushleft
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw [fill=black] (0,0) rectangle (2cm,2cm);
      \node [text=white] at (1cm,1cm) { \chapnumfont\thechapter };
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
  \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
        \hspace*{30mm}\chaptitlefont\MakeUppercase{##1}}}

\makeatletter
\settocpreprocessor{chapter}{%
  \let\tempf@rtoc\f@rtoc%
  \def\f@rtoc{%
  \texorpdfstring{\MakeTextUppercase{\tempf@rtoc}}{\tempf@rtoc}}%
}
\makeatother

%%%%%%
% PAGESTYLE
%%%%%%
\makepagestyle{bachelor}
\makepsmarks{bachelor}{
  \createmark{chapter}      {both}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
  \createmark{section}      {both}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
}
\makeoddhead{bachelor}%
  {}%
  {}%
  {\rightmark}%
\makeevenhead{bachelor}%
  {\leftmark}%
  {}%
  {}
\makeoddfoot{bachelor}
  {} %left
  {} %middle
  {\thepage} %right
\makeevenfoot{bachelor}
  {\thepage} %Left
  {} %middle
  {} %right

\pagestyle{bachelor}

\begin{document}
\chapterstyle{simple}
\chapter{Intro}
\chapterstyle{box}
\chapter{Theory}
\end{document}
```

I want my own chapter style, since I think it's more beautiful than the standard. Unfortunately this make's it more complicated to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) uses the `chapter` page style for the first page of every chapter. The `chapter` page style is considered a *alias* of the `plain` page style. In order to modify an *alias* page style, you first have to make a true copy of the page style:

```
\copypagestyle{chapter}{plain}
```

The above makes a true copy of the `plain` page style and calls it the `chapter` page style. Now adjust the *odd* footer of the `chapter` page style, since the first page of every chapter is set on an odd page by default:

```
\makeoddfoot{chapter}
  {}% Left
  {}% Centre
  {\thepage}% Right
```

Since `memoir` automatically issues `\thispagestyle{chapter}` on the first page of every chapter, there's nothing else you have to do.